# How to pass a filename argument gitconfig diff textconv?

Tags: git, diff, git-config

The documentation on `textconv` at https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv has the succinct wording:

> `~/.gitconfig` must indicate the command to execute for the the textconv driver:
>
> ```
> [diff "<driver_name>"]
>     textconv=<command>
> ```

I cannot find any documentation on how to format a command which requires the filename passed as a positional argument. For example, I'd like to use the following pdf formatter command, which requires a dash as last argument to write to stdout:

```
[diff "pdf"]
    textconv = pdftotext -layout "$1" -
```

For now I've had to write custom one-liner shell-scripts as a workaround, but they start to accumulate, and it becomes a bit annoying.

Is there a way to do without those scripts?
The `"$1"` or xargs' `'{}'` convention for arguments don't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround for `gitconfig` lacking parameter substitution functionality, you can wrap the command into a shell call, as in

```
[diff "pdf"]
    textconv = sh -c 'pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 "$0" -'
```

(found here: https://gist.github.com/t-yuki/9348e5d4aa4a75a6acf9)

Comment: Thanks! This isn't perfect, with the sub-shell call; but since it works and helps me save on extra shell script files, I'll take that as the new answer! nice one

Comment: With windows Git included mingw64 pdftotext it has to be like this:

    [diff "pdf"]
        textconv = sh -c 'pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 "$0" -'

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that information is just plain not available.  [Here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e35b8cb8e212e3557efc565157ceb5cbaaf0d87f/diff.c#L6551-L6588) is the code that actually achieves the text conversion:

```
temp = prepare_temp_file(r, spec->path, spec);
*arg++ = pgm;
*arg++ = temp->name;
*arg = NULL;


child.use_shell = 1;
child.argv = argv;
child.out = -1;
if (start_command(&child)) {
    remove_tempfile();
    return NULL;
}
```

The two arguments are the name of the program itself (argv[0] as usual) and the name of the temporary file containing the bits extracted from wherever they reside (based on the `spec` parameter; follow the link above for additional detail).

The spec probably does carry the original path name in most or all cases (and if not, look at the function just below this one), it's just not copied through to the program arguments.  The textconv filter code could, but doesn't, employ the `%`-expansion technique used by Git merge drivers, and if it did (but it doesn't) it could  has a `%`-escape that passed the original file name.  But of course it doesn't.

(You can make your own clone of Git and work on it, and perhaps try to convince the Git folks to take your change as a contribution to public Git...)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
[diff "pdf"]
    textconv = textconv = "f() { pdftotext -layout "$1" - }; f"
```

It creates a function `f` as vitual command, and executes it (Filename is delivered as `$1`).
For some files (with whitespaces) you maybe need to use `${@}` whats covers all delivered arguments.
So you are complete free with this function to define what you like to execute.

You can also write functions over multiple lines like this:

```
[diff "pdf"]
    textconv = "f() {\
        echo 'My custom textconv'; \
        command1 $1; \
        command2; \
      }; f"
```

Each line mustbe terminated with a backslash to "escape" the linebreak